# Converting xml list data to datatable

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Iam  a beginner in c#  and am just trying to read an xml and return the xml list data to a datatable. This is my code looks like.

```
 public DataTable SearchData(string sData)
        {
            userdata objuserdata = new userdata();
            string Xmlpath = @"d:\Test.xml";


            var Data = XDocument.Load(Xmlpath).Root
                       .Descendants("Field")
                       .Where(element => element.Attribute("Title").Value == "XYZ")
                       .Descendants()
                       .Where(element => element.Name == "Description"
                                         )
                       .Select(element => element.Value).ToList();

            // convert var data to datatable
            //return datatable;
        }
```

How can i convert the data to datatable. can somebody help me

Comment: you can directly convert xml file to datatable using dt.ReadXml(xmlpath);

Answer (score 0):

code would look like this :

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("col_" + col.ToString(), typeof(string));
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.ToString() + "_1", row.ToString() + "_2", row.ToString() + "_3", row.ToString() + "_4", row.ToString() + "_5" });
        }
```